# accessing a property of an instantiated object with my custom init method

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, cocos2d-iphone

Here's my class with my custom init method:

// Piece.h

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Piece : CCSprite

@property (nonatomic) int pieceNumber;

+(Piece *)initWithPieceImage:(UIImage*)piece pieceName:(int)pName;

@end
```

// Piece.m

```c
#import "Piece.h"

@implementation Piece

@synthesize pieceNumber = _pieceNumber;

+(id)initWithPieceImage:(UIImage *)piece pieceName:(int)pName
{
  return [[[self alloc] initWithPieceImage:piece pieceName:pName] autorelease];
}

-(Piece*)initWithPieceImage:(UIImage *)piece pieceName:(int)pName
{
  CCSprite *bgImage = nil;
  if ( (self=[super init]) )
  {
    bgImage = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:piece.CGImage 
                                      key: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",pName]];
  }
  return (Piece*)bgImage;
}
@end
```

I instantiated the **Piece** class like this to add it to the layer:

```c
Piece *newPiece = [Piece initWithPieceImage:myUIImage pieceName:1];
[newPiece setPieceNumber:2];   //Error in this line
[self addChild: newPiece z:1];
```

However I have tried it like this and it perfectly works:

```c
Piece *newPiece = [[Piece alloc] init];
[newPiece setPieceNumber:2];
```

but this is not what I want.

and here is the error I get:

**[CCSprite setPieceNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x85f1050
Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: -[CCSprite   setPieceNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x85f1050**

Aparently it looks like the problem is how Im trying to init my object.

I'm a newcomer to objective-c so I cant figure out what is wrong here.


*any idea of what am I doing wrong here?*

*How can I achieve this approach and access the properties of my instantiated object with custom init method?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mess in your code. In `-(Piece*)initWithPieceImage:(UIImage *)piece pieceName:(int)pName` you return a `CCSprite` object instead of a `Piece`. You assign `self` with an object but return another, of an incorrect type.

`init` returns the correct type (because you haven't reimplemented it), so it works, but you haven't actually initialized the image correctly.

You need to change your method like so:

```
-(Piece*)initWithPieceImage:(UIImage *)piece pieceName:(int)pName
{
    return [super initWithCGImage:piece.CGImage key:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",pName]];
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works great now. I also added the alloc keyword in the return of the static method (return [[self alloc] initWithPieceImage:piece pieceName:pName];)  so that there is no endless recursion like you said.

Comment: @TiagoHuezo Are you using ARC? If not, make sure to take care of memory management. But I recommend you use ARC.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in your init method, you are for some reason creating a CCSprite object and returning that instead of the Piece object. Because of that, it will not be an object of your Piece class and will not respond to any of Piece's methods.

Instead of creating a new CCSprite object to set those properties to, you want to set those on `self` or `super`.

Comment: My bad ignore that last part. I wrote that when I thought that you were doing something else.

Comment: I get lost. I already deleted alloc and autorelease keywords in the initialization in the static method like you said and now it looks like: +(id)initWithPieceImage:(UIImage *)piece pieceName:(int)pName
{
    return [self initWithPieceImage:piece pieceName:pName];
} and after a while the compiler stops in the return line and throws no error message.